# XDカンプと同じコードを入力しても、XD通りのデザインになりません、

Tags: php, wordpress

XDのデザインカンプから、サイトを作成しています。
数字を、デザインと同じにしても、ずれます、主に、 line-height:がです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように、TOEFL対策はEngressの部分などが、実際のXDと同じ数字にしても、文字の上下の感覚が、ずれます。

この場合の対処法は、リセットCSSが悪いのでしょうか？
それとも他の何かが悪いのでしょうか、どなたかお願いいたします。
リセットCSS

```
========================================
    リセットcss
========================================= */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

input, textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th {
  text-align: left;
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```
.Fv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Fv-section .Fv .Fv-img {
  background: url(images/fv.png); 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 476px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
}

.Fv-img-container {
  height: 476px;
}

.Fv .Fv-img div div .Fv-title {
  padding-top: 116px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3541;
  color: #fff;
  height: 53px;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
}

.Fv .Fv-img div .Fv-txt-wrapper {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 49px;
  height: 51px;
  line-height: 1.222;
}



.Fv .Fv-img div .Fv-outer {
  padding-bottom: 22px;
}



.Fv .Fv-img div .Fv-outer a .Fv-outer-btn {
  width: 260px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 31px;
  background-color: #F5A623;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.Fv-outer-btn-second{
  line-height: 29px;
}

.Fv .Fv-img div div .contact-link {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```
<section class="Fv-section">
    <div class="Fv">
        <div class="Fv-img">
            <div class="Fv-img-container">
                <div class="Fv-title-wrapper">
                    <h2 class="Fv-title">TOEFL対策はEngress</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="Fv-title-wrapper-second">
                <p class="Fv-txt-wrapper">日本へのTOEFL指導歴豊かな講師陣の<br>
                    コーチング型TOEFLスクール
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class="Fv-outer">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <div class="Fv-outer-btn">
                            <p class="Fv-outer-btn-second">資料請求</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-link-second">
                    <a class="contact-link" href="#">
                        <p class="contact-link-second">お問い合わせ</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: 貴方の他の質問もそうですが、他の人が問題を再現・調査・検証するために十分な(テキストによる)ソースコードや情報が書かれていないように見えます。自己解決したものも、質問記事に書いて無い他の人が知り得ない部分を修正して解決したように見えます。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に、助言・回答する人に十分な情報を提示するようにしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 例えばこの質問だとHTMLは画像で一部分だけだし、「リセットCSSが悪いのでしょうか？」と書かれていてもそのリセットCSSは何処のどんな物かの情報が無いでしょう。

Comment: すいません、リセットCSS追加します。

Comment: 垂直方向の文字の揃えの設定はXDだとどうなっています？コンテンツのサイズに比べてなんかやけに上下に分かれていているような気もしています。もしかして高さに対してline-heightがあふれている可能性もあるかなと思いますけど。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます、上の画像にあるもの以外にも、XDで分かる情報があるのですか？ちょっと垂直方向の文字揃えの設定の見方がわかりません。line-heightは、行間割るフォントサイズでやっていますが、設定したheightに収まりませんのでずれることがあります。